# rename the end of filename by subtracting value

Tags: macos, sed, file-rename

I have on macOS the following files in ns_up/ directory:

```
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_260.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_261.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_262.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_263.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_264.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_265.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_266.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_267.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_268.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_269.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_270.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_271.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_272.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_273.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_274.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_275.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_276.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_277.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_278.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_279.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_280.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_281.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_282.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_283.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_284.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_285.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_286.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_287.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_288.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_289.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_290.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_291.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_292.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_293.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_294.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_295.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_296.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_297.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_298.dat
sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_299.dat
```

I would like to rename each of one by subtracting the value 200 at the end of the filename, for example :

sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_299.dat = sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_99.dat

I tried the following thing :

```bash
for i in $(ls ns_up/); do
  number=$(echo $i | gsed 's/\(.*\)_\(.*\).dat/\2/')
  new_number=$((number-200))
  echo $i | gsed 's/_\(.*\)\.dat/"\$new_number"\.dat/'
done
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't work and I don't know why.

Anyone would have an idea?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes - both extremely important, absolute basics of shell programming that everyone HAS to learn and follow to avoid shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: @EdMorton, in the opinion of ShellCheck, quoting is only required when your inputs are unknown. See this demo [here](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/1e09d0502516d87ca4ea6805c8611adf).

Comment: No. Quoting is what you do by default. You **remove** quotes when you **need** to to get the shell to do globbing, word splitting, etc., you don't **add* quotes when you need to. Behaving otherwise will bite you in the ass one day when a script that worked just fine for 6 months suddenly fails cryptically and/or disastrously just because some new input shows up. There are cases when you must leave a variable unquoted to get specific behavior so I'd have been surprised if shellcheck did report an unquoted variable as an error since it has no way to know your intent in leaving it unquoted.

Comment: @AlexHarvey meant to tag you in the above ^

Comment: @EdMorton, fyi I have raised a query against ShellCheck [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/1567).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install (Perl) `rename` with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```

Then try:

```
rename -n 's/(\d+)/$1 - 200/e' ns_up/*dat
```

The `-n` says to do a *"dry run"*, i.e. say what it would do, without actually doing anything.

The Perl expression in single quotes, receives each filename in turn in variable `$_` and is expected to modify it and return the new value in the same variable.

The substitution says *"substitute any bunch of adjacent digits it finds with that number minus 200."*

The `e` says to **evaluate** the right side of the substitution.

This approach has some added benefits:

- you can do a dry run easily
- it will not clobber files if any two input filenames were to result in the same output filename
- see man page for many more advantages

Comment: @Setchell . thanks for your answer. What precisely the meaning of `(\d+)`in your expression : does it mean "at least contains more than one digit ?" and `+' at least one element ? Regards

Comment: `\d` means a single digit, `\d+` one, or more digits. So it just means *"a load of digits next to each other"*.

Comment: if we had set `\d*`, this would have meant zero or multiple digits (diffence between `+`and `*`symbol), wouldn't this ?

Comment: It would have meant that, yes.

Comment: last question, parentesis into `(\d+)` are really necessary or is just proper to rename function (it look likes `\(.*\)` with sed for template that we print with `\1`) ? I stop to bore you, thanks

Comment: It's a Perl *"capture group"*. Basically, whatever you capture inside the first pair of `()` on the left becomes available to you as `$1` on the right of the substitution. Whatever you capture in the second `()` on the left is available as `$2` on the right.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel --dryrun mv {} '{= s/(\d+)/$1 - 200/e =}' ::: *.dat
```

Remove the `--dryrun` option once the generated commands have been checked.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're trying to do (using bash for BASH_REMATCH[] and $((..)) arithmetic operation):

```
for old in ns_up/*.dat; do
    [[ $old =~ ^(.*)_(.*)(\.dat)$ ]] || { printf 'Warning, unexpected old file name format "%s"\n' "$old" >&2; continue; }
    new="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$((${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-200))${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    [[ -f "$new" ]] && { printf 'Warning, new file name "%s" generated from "%s" already exists, skipping.\n' "$new" "$old" >&2; continue; }
    mv -- "$old" "$new"
done
```

You need that test for new already existing since a new file name may be the same as an existing one and you probably don't want to overwrite it.

Comment: But would you _really_ do all that just to rename a bunch of files? :)

Comment: @AlexHarvey If it was a one-off where I **knew** 100% that I didn't need the warnings for this particular input set then I wouldn't bother with them but would do the rest which would leave no more code than your solution but more robust and efficient . If it was a script I wanted to be able to reuse some other time or wasn't 100% certain of my input then I'd include the tests and warnings,

Comment: Anyway, definitely a cleaner solution than calling sed for obtaining the file number and file name strings.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed:

```
   find . -iregex '.+sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_2[0-9]+\.dat' -exec sh -c 'mv {} `echo {}|sed -E "s/(.+_)2([0-9]+\.dat)/\1\2/"`' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your command is that you have no `mv` command there and you don't compute the left part of the new file name. This works:

```bash
▶ for i in ns_up/* ; do
    n=$(echo "$i" | gsed -E 's/(.*)_([0-9]+).dat/\2/')
    new_n=$((n - 200))
    left=$(echo "$i" | gsed -E 's/[0-9]+.*//')
    mv -i "$i" "$left${new_n}.dat"
  done
```

Notes:

- I have specified `mv -i` to guard against accidentally overwriting a file.
- I have used `-E` to the sed command to use Extended Regular Expressions, allowing for a cleaner syntax here.
- I used `gsed -E 's/(.*)_([0-9]+).dat/\2/'` rather than your `gsed 's/\(.*\)_\(.*\).dat/\2/'` because matching the `[0-9]+` (number) explicitly is clearer and more explicit about which underscore you are matching.